# VBA, Search if file name exists in Network Drive

Tags: vba, excel

Does anyone have a macro where I can input a list of file names in excel,(Full path in Col A) and search to see if they exist on a network drive(not local)?

Is it possible to show in Col B:

1) If file exists? (true or false)
 2) the timestamp of the file? (time file created and/or modified)

Tried searching for this, but would like to use a VBA code.

Example: Col A has my file names, and I want Col B to show if they exist in the network drive, and C showing the timestamp if it exits.

Thanks.

Comment: to achieve this you need to map network drive as local

Comment: @Karthick , Hi Karthick, so I would need to copy all files from network to local?

Comment: No pls see my answer below

Comment: Does column A include fully-qualified file names (e.g. \\networklocation\somefolder\someotherfolder\somefile.txt) or just the file name (somefile.txt)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to show that the file exists or not, you could use this simple code that I use almost everywhere. It is small, fast and also checks for files in Local machine or on Network.

```
Public Function CheckIfFileExists(FilePath As String)

On Error GoTo ExitWithError

If FilePath = "" Then
    CheckIfFileExists = ""
    Exit Function
End If
If Dir(FilePath) <> "" Then
    CheckIfFileExists = "File found"
Else
    CheckIfFileExists = "File not found"
End If

Exit Function
ExitWithError:
    CheckIfFileExists = "File not accessible"
End Function
```

And for the TimeStamp you can use the following code -

```
Public Function getTimestampOfFile(FilePath As String)

On Error GoTo ExitWithError

If FilePath = "" Then
    Exit Function
End If
If Dir(FilePath) <> "" Then
'This creates an instance of the MS Scripting Runtime FileSystemObject class
Set oFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

getTimestampOfFile = oFS.GetFile(FilePath).DateCreated
Else
End If

Exit Function
ExitWithError:
MsgBox "Error"
End Function
```

And now your functions are ready to use!  Like this --

[Use the file exists function as if it is excel's in-build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdKgm.png)

[Do the same for timestamp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDf4n.png)

I hope that it helps you.

Thanks,
RK.

Comment: See my screenshots attached, just add the filepath(whatever it is) to some cell, write the formula and give cell reference where the file path is stored.

Comment: In case your file path is local, value in cell will be something like this - 'C:/Users/......'. In case your file path is on network, value will look like this - 'SomeComputerName//SharedFiles//SomePath//SomeFolder//SomeFile.someextension

Comment: Thanks Rehban, where precisely to I enter where the file path is stored? I put it between `If Dir(FilePath) <> "") Then` , get syntax error.

Comment: Do I have to alter your code to show where Im looking?

Comment: I have my local in my cells, and I get its a function, just how do I alter the code to check the network drive?

Comment: Don't need to alter it, this will check for files on the network too (Obviously if you have access)

Comment: Having trouble :( , I didnt alter the code, getting error on the `If Dir(FilePath) <> "") Then` line , I do have access. I see the file exist in network, because if I click the file name I can open the file.

Comment: Sorry about that, I've edited the code. Let me know if it works now..

Comment: By Golly it works!! Just getting an error on the timestamp `MsgBox 'Error'` part.

Comment: Change 'Error' to "Error" and you're good to go! I have updated the code

Comment: Wow thanks rehban! if you have any other cool functions like this that give any file details, would you share?

Comment: Also if I want to just get th time without the time created part, how do I do that?

Comment: https://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/433456-how-extract-just-time-portion-datetime .Check Steve's answer on this link. He explains all formats of date and how can we achieve it in vba. Thanks Jonathan.

Comment: Wait Rehban!!! lol, if my file has a *.csv at the end, and the * may imply a character or number, is there a way I can get the function to treat it as such? Or do I have to replace it with a sample?

Comment: Hi Rehban, when I speak of the date, I mean just want  the date and time, no file name and created on part. (referring to your comment about Steve)

Comment: I updated the code, Is that fine now?

Comment: I notice the time is different that this  function shows then the date modified in the detail view of the network drive, is there a way of getting both?

Comment: You need last modified time or creation date?

Comment: For last modified time, you just replace (FilePath).DateCreated with (FilePath).DateLastModified

Comment: Can we spit out the error'd files into a separate sheet?

Comment: Not sure about that Jonathan, you can add a different question for that if you want...

Comment: is there any other file detail I can modify these to? Any that would be handy? just curious.

Comment: Hi Rehban, do know how the timestamp can work for files with wildcards at the end? Example : Rehban/Khatri_*.csv . Seems to return 12:00. Probably because the wildcard can apply to many files, is there a way to take the max time of these wildcards

Answer (score 1):

This `Sub` loops through all files on your network share. You can grab the creation date, modified date, and last access date. This will only get files that exist. All you have to do then is input the data where you want them.

You will need to add a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime by going to Tools > References and selecting that option.

**EDITED:**

```
Sub FileHandler()

 Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
 Dim fold As Scripting.folder
 Dim f As Range, checkF As Scripting.file
 Dim networkExistsCell As Range, timeStamp As Range

 Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
 Set fold = fso.GetFolder("\\your_network_share\")


' Disk access is the slow part, so structure the loops so each file on disk is only checked once.

  For Each checkF In fold.Files

    For Each f In Range("A1:A30")
      If checkF.Name = f.Value Then
        rowNum = f.Row
        Set networkExistsCell = Range("B" + Trim(Str(rowNum)))
        Set timeStamp = Range("C" + Trim(Str(rowNum)))
        networkExistsCell.FormulaR1C1 = checkF.Name
        timeStamp.FormulaR1C1 = Format(checkF.DateCreated, "MM-DD-YYYY")
      End If
    Next f

  Next checkF

End Sub
```

*Edit - moved the cell loop inside of the file loop*

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.  Where do I load my paths I want to find? Say I have them in Col A, where will this handler spit the info?

Comment: Do you want the user to select a folder and type in a name? Right now this isn't spitting out anything anywhere. You would spit it out in the `If` in your `For Each`

Comment: The user to submit maybe say 30 file names, see if they exist in the drive. So instead of choosing local folder, maybe just have only the files names in cells column A of a sheet, then these names listed in ColA would be searched in the network drive.

Comment: Edited. I think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: When possible, try to only loop through the files on disk once; `FileSystemObject` is a really slow object. Move the `For Each f in Range("A1:A30")` loop inside the `For Each checkF in fold.Files`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your filenames starts with A1, A2 and so on.. if file exists the timestamp will print at corresponding B columns B1, B2 and so on..

Map your network drive to local by follow these steps

> Open the network drive and Select Tools ---> Map Network Drive ---> copy the network location folder and paste in to Folder box and Finish

Assume that your local network drive is Z:\

```
Sub testing()
    ChDir ("z:\)
    lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To lastrow
        If Dir(Range("A" & i).Value) <> "" Then
            out = ShowFileAccessInfo(Range("A" & i).Value)
            Range("B" & i).Value = out
        Else
            'File NOt Exists
        End If
    Next i
End Sub


Function ShowFileAccessInfo(filespec)
  ChDir ("Z:\")
  Dim fso, f, s
  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Set f = fso.GetFile(filespec)
  s = UCase(filespec) & "<BR>"
  s = s & "Created: " & f.DateCreated & "<BR>"
  s = s & "Last Accessed: " & f.DateLastAccessed & "<BR>"
  s = s & "Last Modified: " & f.DateLastModified
  ShowFileAccessInfo = s
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Karthick, what does Map Network Drive do? Will this affect the network drive? Is this solution possible to do without mapping it?

Comment: you are just mapping network as your local drive thats all

Comment: Meaning a copy? Okay ill try this out and let you know how it goes.

Comment: No not a copy. Please have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drive_mapping

Comment: Will this affect the network drive? The network drive must remain intact and not be altered in any way.

Comment: `DIR` has much better performance than `FileSystemObject`, especially for network access. You can use it on file shares without mapping the drive, though; `dir("\\your_file_share\" & fileName)` will work.

Comment: @Jonathan it will not affect your network drive. we are getting the timestamp only